# Environment for test IIDR-IBM

Tags: ibm-data-replication

I'm new to using IBM IIDR and I am considering using IIDR to do data replication between DB2 - kafka - Postgresql but I can't find an easy way to test this software, I know that the management console and access server can be obtained from IBM central fix, but how can I get the CDC to test on my local machine?
Any help i will appreciate it a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can find the replication engines for Db2, Kafka and PostgreSQL on [FixCentral](http://www.ibm.com/support/fixcentral/swg/quickorder?parent=ibm%7EInformation%20Management&product=ibm/Information%20Management/IBM%20InfoSphere%20Data%20Replication&release=11.4&platform=Linux%2064-bit,x86_64&function=all&source=fc) as well.

For example, the *IBM InfoSphere Data Replication CDC for all Linux agents 11.4.0.2 Build x* installer has all the Linux x64 engines.

The installer will ask you which database type you would like to use. If you will be replicating from PostgreSQL, please select "PostgreSQL source". If you will replicate to PostgreSQL, select "FlexRep". For Kafka and Db2, simply select the matching entry.

To get started with CDC for Kafka, I recommend starting with [this CDC Kafka Installation and Configuration guide](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/node/6211917). More resources are available on the [IBM Data Replication wiki](https://ibm.biz/idrwiki#Kafka).

To get started with CDC for PostgreSQL as a target, see the [JDBC configuration information in Knowledge Center](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSTRGZ_11.4.0/com.ibm.cdcdoc.cdcflexrep.doc/concepts/supportedflexrepjdbcdrivers.html). For PostgresSQL as a source, [check here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSTRGZ_11.4.0/com.ibm.cdcdoc.postgresql.doc/concepts/before_install.html) for required database user privileges and settings.

CDC for Db2 has a number of deployment options to choose from, [described here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSTRGZ_11.4.0/com.ibm.cdcdoc.cdcfordb2luw.doc/concepts/before_install.html).

If you can't find the info you need, [reach out to the IBM Data Replication support team](https://ibm.biz/idrsupport).

Hope that helps,

Sarah

IBM Data Replication development